# How do I access enum by int or by string

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enum:

```
public enum Difficulty {
    EASY(2), MEDUIM(3), HARD(5), EXTREME(8);

    private int length;

    Difficulty(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public int length() {
        return length;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to reach the correct enum instance whether I know the number or the name.
For instance, if I have the int `3`, I need a simple function that is able to return `MEDIUM`. And if I have the string `extreme` I need a simple function that is able to return `8`.
By simple, I mean that I don't want to iterate each time or keep a static array inside the enum.

Answer must be in Java, Please. Thanks.
 What edits do I need to make to the `Difficulty` enum structure?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Difficulty getByName(String name) {
    return valueOf(name.toUpperCase());
}

public static Difficulty getByLength(int length) {
    switch (length) {
        case 2:
            return EASY;
        case 3:
            return MEDIUM;
        case 5:
            return HARD;
        case 8:
            return EXTREME;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid length : " + length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `switch`, why not scan through `Difficulty.values()` for a difficulty with the specified id?

Comment: This is iteration by another name: you are switching exhaustively. So if no one else responds, I will have to accept that there is no other way. +1 for the first method. thanks.

Comment: @BorisB. agreed. I did it to avoid iterating, as the user asked, but a loop would be cleaner.